# What is the difference between sich unterhalten and sprechen

Tags: verb, verb-choice, verb-usage

I am talking on skpe with my German friends.

> Ich spreche mit meinen deutschen Freunden auf Skype.

Can I also use `sich unterhalten` in this context?
What is the difference between `sprechen`and `sich unterhalten`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Sich unterhalten` means to have a conversation, i.e. it involves both talking and listening. `Sprechen` simply means to speak: you do that in a conversation, too, but it can also be one-sided. Think of der Sprecher (speaker), der Lautsprecher (loudspeaker), der Fernsprecher (old word for telephone), der Fürsprecher (intercessor) etc.

Answer (score 4):

Ja, in diesem Kontext bedeuten "mit jemandem sprechen" und "sich mit jemandem unterhalten" das Gleiche.

"Sich mit jemandem unterhalten" ist ein Dialog. Ich kann auch als Redner zu einem Publikum sprechen, dann bin ich derjenige, der meistens spricht, und die anderen hören zu.

Comment: Allerdings spricht der Redner eben nicht *mit* dem Publikum, sondern *zum* Publikum. "Sprechen *mit*" impliziert in der Regel schon ein Gespräch.

Comment: Das habe ich doch geschrieben?

Comment: Dass "sprechen mit" in der Regel ein Gespräch impliziert, hast Du nicht geschrieben. Nur, dass es in diesem Kontext das gleiche ist wie "sich unterhalten" (was eine wesentlich engere Aussage ist).

Comment: Ich fand meine Antwort recht klar in dem Unterschied zwischen "sprechen mit" und "sprechen zu". Aber spätestens mit Deiner Ergänzungn sollten jetzt alle Zweifel ausgeräumt sein.

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy to explain the difference between sich unterhalten and sprechen.
sich unterhalten (mit jemandem):
That seems relatively easy: to have a talk with someone and to talk about this and that. A kind of socializing act.

sprechen: 
It has several uses and constructions.
eine Fremdsprache sprechen, Sprechen Sie Englisch/Deutsch?

On the phone/ at the reception:
Kann ich bitte Herrn X sprechen? - Ich möchte bitte den Direktor sprechen.
In this case  the caller has a special matter he wants to bring forward.

Ein Redner kann zu Zuhörern sprechen, über ein Thema.

In some cases sprechen and sich unterhalten are interchangeable.